# Magento XML Newsletter issue

Tags: xml, magento, newsletter

I'm trying to add an xml newsletter block onto a page. Because the template is set up to put the block on the home page I've created a cms page and have changed around the code from:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter"  template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

To:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="home.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

I've checked the settings in Magento and the newsletter module is enabled but is still not appearing on the page. Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
You create a cms/block and place the below code

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

**Step 2:** Call that cms/block in any page like this. Place the below code in your template file wherever you want.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('YOUR IDENTIFIER')->toHtml() ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've called the block okay and got it to appear but the actual newsletter box doesn't show. I created a block called 'newsletter' and have used this code

    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('newsletter')->toHtml(); ?>

In the xml file the code is:

            <reference name="content">
            <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="home.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
        </reference>

Is this all correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="home.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/> </reference>
```

To

```
<reference name="root">
    <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="home.newsletter" as="home.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

and under your cms page call newsletter

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('home.newsletter') ?>
```